# How can i iterate the json after deserialization?

Tags: json, struts2, deserialization

In my applicatin I am passing a json array from jsp to action calss using ajax. In the action class I am obtaining the json and deserializing it using the below code.

I am getting the Hash map inside the person list. How can I get the individual entries inside the person list?

```
String personList = request.getParameter("PersonCollections");
List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) JSONUtil
            .deserialize(personList);
```

Comment: Please be a bit more descriptive regarding what you're actually getting. If `person` is a list (in which case it should be named `people` or at least `persons`), you get it like you would from any other list.

Comment: You could just use the JSON plugin, it covers common use-cases. Do you mean how to you get them with java (for each loop)? Or how do you iterate them in a JSP (struts2 iterator tag, and property tag)?